# Internal Server Error and bad CSS

Tags: server-load, 500-internal-error, shared-hosting

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce website that is facing a lot of Internal Server Errors and sometimes even bad CSS.
An example of bad CSS:

[image]

The site loads like this at times, when it should load like this:

[image]

The site has the following plugins installed:

> Akismet, Code Snippets, Mailchimp, Max Mega Menu, Nav Menu Roles, Pie
>   Register, Virtue/Pinnacle Toolkit, Woocommerce, Woocommerce PDF
>   Invoices & Packing Slips, Woocommerce Product SKU Generator, Wordpress
>   Social Login, YITH WooCommerce Wishlist.

The site is hosted on a shared Linux server from [here](http://www.siliconvalley.co.in/). It has about 1TB of memory and 5GB of disk space. The error log in cPanel shows the following errors, regarding the internal server error:

> Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process:
>   /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for public_html/index.php, referer: [URL to the
>   page trying to be opened]
>
> Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process:
>   /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php,
>   referer: [URL to the page trying to be opened]

I cannot understand if a plugin has some bad code hogging too much memory, or if the shared server is not able to take the load of the amount of plugins we have on the site.

Comment: This looks like a server configuration error and not a Wordpress problem. At least that's where you need to start. Probably allowing too many children on one of the services running on your server. Server configuration seems off topic for this area.

Comment: While server configuration for WordPress specifics is considered in scope here, this seems like a more generic issue. Especially since WP isn't typically involved in serving static resources like CSS stylesheets at all.

Comment: So I should take this to server fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its failing to load the CSS for Max Mega Menu.

Under Appearance > Max Mega Menu > Global Settings, try changing CSS Output to 'load in head'

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just applied this. Will test for a day or two and get back to you.

Comment: Didn't fix the internal server errors but did fix the bad css. Thanks.